# Processing multiple pages, radio button selections in a single instance and submit choices

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, laravel

My question1.blade.php

```css
.privew {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .questionsBox {
            display: block;
            border: solid 1px #e3e3e3;
            padding: 10px 20px 0px;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(000,000,000,0.1), inset 0 0 4px rgba(255,255,255,1);
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }.questions {
             background: #007fbe;
             color: #FFF;
             font-size: 22px;
             padding: 8px 30px;
             font-weight: 300;
             margin: 0 -30px 10px;
             position: relative;
         }
        .questions:after {
            background: #1d68a7 no-repeat left 0;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            width: 9px;
            height: 7px;
            content: '.';
            left: 0;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 0;
        }
        .questions:after {
            left: auto;
            right: 0;
            background-position: -10px 0;
        }
        .questions:before, .questions:after {
            background: black;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            width: 9px;
            height: 7px;
            content: '.';
            left: 0;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 0;
        }
        .answerList {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }


        ol, ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
        .answerList li:first-child {
            border-top-width: 0;
        }

        .answerList li {
            padding: 3px 0;
        }
        .answerList label {
            display: block;
            padding: 6px;
            border-radius: 6px;
            border: solid 1px #dde7e8;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 13px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
            margin: 4px 0 0;
            margin-top: 1px;
            line-height: normal;
        }
        .questionsRow {
            background: #dee3e6;
            margin: 0 -20px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
        }
        .button, .greyButton {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            color: #888888;
            display: inline-block;
            border: solid 3px #cccccc;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
            line-height: 27px;
            min-width: 160px;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-radius: 0px;
            text-transform: capitalize;
        }
        .questionsRow span {
            float: right;
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 30px;
            border: solid 1px #aeb9c0;
            padding: 0 10px;
            background: #FFF;
            color: #007fbe;
        }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="privew">
    <div class="questionsBox">
        <div class="questions"><h1>Something</h1></div>
        <div class="answerList"><h3>You are only allowed to select one option from the given below question</h3></div>
        <div class="questions"><h4>Question 1</h4></div>
        <div class="questions"><h3>Section 1</h3></div>
        <ul class="answerList">
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="answerGroup" value="0" id="answerGroup_0">Yes</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="answerGroup" value="1" id="answerGroup_1">Rather yes</label>
            </li>
            <li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="questionsBox">
            <div class="questions"><h3>Section 2</h3></div>
            <ul class="answerList">
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="answerGroup" value="2" id="answerGroup_2">Yes</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="answerGroup" value="3" id="answerGroup_3">Rather yes</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="questionsRow"><a href="{{ route('ques2') }}" class="button" id="nextquestions">Next</a><span>1 from 20</span><a href="{{ route('ques20') }}" class="button" id="nextquestions">Previous</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</body>
```

Hello All,

I'm trying to make a test page where users will select one radio button option and submit all selections in one instance in order to store back into the database. Also, questions are on different pages so basically user can move back and forth in order to edit its selection. There are 20 questions in total. I am unable to understand where shall I put my array logic. My best guess would be in a TestController. Please drop your valuable answer.

P.S : I am a beginner in Web Development and recently started to work on a Personality assessment website Project. However, due to less experience, I am facing a lot of challenges to achieve building it.

This problem is from my Laravel 6.x Project.

I expect to get all the selections stored in an array and passed to the database where I can further process it.